# Trimming read input with Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I am trying to replace space in my input Makefile. The problem I am having is if I

`echo "TRIM THIS" ${$$module | tr " " "_"};`

I get a response like `TRIM_THIS_text_me` when what I just want is `TRIM THIS text_me`

how can I show my desired output.

```
ech:
    @read -p "Enter Module Name:" module; \
    echo "TRIM THIS" $$module | tr " " "_";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're piping all the output of `echo` to `tr`, not just the variable.

There's no need to use `tr` for this, use bash's built-in substitution operator

```
ech:
    @read -p "Enter Module Name:" module; \
    module=$${module// /_} \
    echo TRIM THIS "$$module"
```

Comment: This is different when you are getting your input from `@read`

Comment: Why would it be different? After you set a variable, it doesn't matter where it came from.

Comment: `module` is received from terminal so you access the value like `$$module`

Comment: yeah, forgot that this was in a makefile

Comment: Note, this is not portable at all as written.  Make always invokes `/bin/sh` as the shell to run recipes in.  On systems where `/bin/sh` is not the same as `bash` (for example, Debian/Ubuntu systems) then this won't work.  Using `tr` is much more portable.  If you are OK with requiring people to have `bash` in order to run this makefile you need to add `SHELL := /bin/bash` to your makefile.